# How to Access Custom tab/buttons created using Ribbon.xml for Visio 2010 using C#4.0

Tags: c#, vsto, ribbon, visio

All,

I have created Visio 2010 Addin project in C# 4.0. i creaded the custom ribbon using Ribbon.xml.
I need to access custom tabs or buttons Id's to changes the label/name of control at runtime.

Help Appreciated.

-Sach

Answer (score 0):

That callback functions give you IRibbonControl sender.  I use sender.Id as a reference and lookup the other properties in the Ribbon.XML string from the GetCustomUI() function.  If you change another control's label (referenced via getLabel="myFunction" in the XML), be sure to use IRibbonUI.InvalidateControl to refresh it.